# How to get Google Directions to stay on a specified route to get somewhere?

Tags: java, android, google-directions-api

I'm developing an Android app, but I'm not sure how to do the next thing: there is one biking route that we've chosen. The users should get directions for continuing along this biking road.

So Google Directions should stay on my route and not choose a road that is not within my route to get to the end of the biking road.

Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: How you have chosen your route? Over Google Directions with waypoints or with a ordinary map?

Comment: I haven't programmed anything yet for the directions or route. I've got the road on another google map. Are you saying I could do this using markers? The map on Android is an ordinary map I guess, with some markers concerning important stuff to visit (it's not the route).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you wanna have a route from Google Directions, which should match your determined route.

Well, it could be hard to manage that because Directions is designed to find the shortest path between two points. One way is to use the option of waypoints, to limit the suggestions of the API. Simple said, don't use just a origin and a destination. Use as much waypoints as you have to between the origin and the destination to get the nearest route possible.

Getting the exact route as you think of it is just big luck.

Comment: Alright, I knew the client(sort-of, it's a freebie but, the person who wanted this to be made) was not asking for something easy. So what do you think about this idea? I get all the road names in a particular order (from a->b) in an array. I check if the current user's road is in it and use directions towards the next road.

Comment: If you have all the road names before you call Directions, just use the first as `&origin=` the last as `&destination=` and all roads between as `&waypoint=`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that!